# Haskell alternative for Doubly-linked-list coupled with Hash-table pattern

Tags: haskell

There's a useful pattern in imperative programming, namely, a doubly-linked-list coupled with a hash-table for constant time lookup in the linked list.

One application of this pattern is in LRU cache. The head of the doubly-linked-list will contain the least recently used entry in the cache and the last element in the doubly-linked-list will contain the most recently used entry. The keys in the hash-table are keys of the entries and the values are pointers to nodes in the linked-list corresponding to the key/entry. When an entry is queried in the cache, hash-table will be used to point to its node in the linked-list and then the node will be removed from its current location in the linked-list and be placed at the end of the linked-list making it the most-recently-used entry. For eviction, we simply remove entries from the head of the linked-list as they are the least recently used ones. Both lookup and eviction operations will take constant time.

I can think of implementing this in Haskell using two TreeMaps and I know that the time complexity will be O(log n). But I am a little uncomfortable as the constant factor in the time complexity seems a little high. Specifically, to perform a look-up, first I need to check if the entry exists and save its value, then I need to first delete it from the LRU map and re-insert it with a new key. This means that each lookup will result in a root-to-node traversal three times.

Is there a better way of doing this in Haskell?

Comment: You can do the same using mutable vectors in Haskell.

Comment: Yeah; as this data structure is fundamentally about side-effects (under-used entries are kicked out – _not nice_, referential-transperencywise speaking!) using the `ST` monad for actual mutable structures seems the way to go.

Comment: @freestyle Yes I know but I am looking for a Haskell idiomatic solution if possible. Mutable vectors do not seem idiomatic Haskell to me.

Comment: Wrapped in the right monad, mutable vectors are perfectly idiomatic Haskell, so long as you need something mutable and vector-shaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As comments indicate, mutable vectors are perfectly acceptable when required. However, I think there's an issue with the way you've stated the question - unless the idea is to duplicate "as closely as possible" (without mutable structures) the imperative code, why bother having 2 treemaps? A single priority search queue (see packages [`pqueue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pqueue) or [`PSQueue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/PSQueue)) would be an appropriate structure whilst maintaining purity. It supports efficiently both priorities (for eviction) and searching (for lookups of your desired cached argument).

On a related note, some structures support eg. [`Data.Map`'s `alterF`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:alterF), which effectively provides you with a continuation allowing you to "do something else" dependent on the `Maybe` value at a key, but "remembering" where you are and thus avoiding to pay the full cost to re-traverse the structure to subsequently modify at this key. See also [the `at` lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:at).

Comment: `alterF` does require the tree to be walked a second time, but doesn't require the keys to be loaded and compared again along the way; the location in the tree is stored using a two-word bit list that (very compactly and efficiently) represents the sequence of left and right branches needed to find the key. It's not very pretty, but the more natural ways to do it turn out to be much slower for many functors.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, I didn't know that! Is there a blog post or w/e going into your final sentence in more detail? because it's not obvious why that should be the case. My intuition says you could design different types of zippers on trees, one which remembers the branching as you described, or another which rotates the structure such that the node under focus is constant-time accessible. Practically the latter is unwieldly and/or slow?

Comment: Practically, the latter tends to require memory to be allocated as you descend the tree, which ultimately leads to poor performance. The obvious thing is to code `alterF` a lot like `traverse`, but to target only one element. If you think about `traverse`, it says (roughly) `traverse f (Bin s k v l r) = Bin s k <$> f v <*> traverse f l <*> traverse f r`. You have to map over the functor at each level. For `traverse`, the cost of mapping at a node is shared by all the descendents. But for `alterF`, there's only *one* relevant descendant.

Comment: If you want to think about the process more explicitly, you can implement `alterF` using a zipper. But you'll have to allocate one "breadcrumb" for each level in the tree. The bit queue can be seen as a sort of "virtual zipper", indexing into the existing structure instead of actually rotating it.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about priority search queue. I learned about implementing it from the following paper. https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/ICFP01.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This was a really great answer! I've edited it to add some links to the packages you mentioned.